# What DNS record can redirect to a different domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, nameserver

I have a domain registered foo.co.il

I have a temporary free web hosting - foo.3owl.com and I would like to define the DNS records so that when a user tries to access foo.co.il he will be forwarded (hopefully without knowing) to
foo.3owl.com.

To make it clear - since it's a temporary free hosting i can't use the IP (cause it's shared hosting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no DNS based solution to this.  Either the webserver must be setup to respond to both names as the same virtual host so you can use the same address.  Or you need a seperate webserver which proxies or redirects to the site you want them to go to.